# Подскажите идею как стилизовать слайдер

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Сижу над задачей: как стилизовать слайдер:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу высказаться относительно идеи, как обычный слайдер стилизовать таким образом.
Спасибо.

Comment: стилизовать всмысле реализовать?

Comment: Было бы хорошо пояснить словами, как это «таким образом». Сейчас во-первых, непонятно какие ответы могли бы Вас устроить, во-вторых, вопрос тяжело найти в поиске.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот этот слайдер - [**Vue Carousel 3D**](https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/)
[**Вот тут**](https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/examples/) много примеров

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    slides: 7
  },
  components: {
    'carousel-3d': Carousel3d.Carousel3d,
    'slide': Carousel3d.Slide
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/js/vue-carousel-3d.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/js/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <carousel-3d>
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/360x270">
    </slide>
  </carousel-3d>
</div>
```